# Infinite room, camera offset calculations

Tags: javascript, math, game-engine

I'm developing a game engine. the room measures 10000 x 10000 points and the camera (a canvas) 800 x 600. the room represents a space infinity and objects that exceed limit reappear on the other side. the problem arises when the camera rectangle crosses at least one limit, 
objects on the other side of the limit should appear as if it were a continuous space. 
I've tried several ways to do this but none of them seems an elegant solution.
any ideas?

**VIEWPORT**

[image]

the four red boxes are the camera. the 4 blue boxes are the visible part of room

make objects is passed to the other side it's easy. but to calculate what objects draw and the offset applied to each of them (offset within the canvas).. my mind is in blank. 
i need to find a optimal solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could print the scene two times. Let's say the top border of the scene is inside your viewport: you print the scene once above that border and once below. You can do the same for the other borders. This can be optimized, obviously, but should work.

Comment: I suppose you have a function to print the scene: first you do that in the 'normal' position (let's say the one that matches the A rectangle). Then you shift the context up by the height of the scene and print it again (this way, you print the C corner); then you shift the context right by the width of the scene and print it again (this way you print the D corner); finally you shift the context down by the height of the scene and print corner B. Also, see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_translate.asp

Answer (score 0):

An alternative using the modulo operator to achieve translation. See the example at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sZv3H/6/)

Using an image as a room and a canvas as a viewport the following code allows the room to be viewed as a wrap around in the canvas.

Try values for dx and dy to see the effect.
In practice the img tag would not be used so that the room would only be seen through the viewport of the canvas

in

```
<img id='room'>
<canvas id='canv' width=100 height=75></canvas>
```

the code

```
im=new Image();
im.src='http://www.all-sweets.com/gradient-wallpaper/gradient-background/gradient-background-3.jpg';
im.onload=function() {
    document.getElementById('room').src=im.src; 
    c=document.getElementById('canv');
    cx=c.getContext('2d');
    cw=c.width;
    ch=c.height;
    iw=im.width;
    ih=im.height;
    x=0;//x value of  top left corner of viewport
    y=0;//y value of top left corner of viewport
    //displacement much less than image width or height
    //build up of displacement move viewport
/*************************************************************** 
Displacements would be set as viewport moves
Manually change these values below to see effect on viewport.
Shown image is 400px by 300px
set dx to 350   and dy to 260 for example to see overlap effect
****************************************************************/
    dx=0;//displacement from current x
    dy=0;//displacement from current y

//*************************************************************** 
    x+=dx;//new x position
    x=x%iw; //modulo translates relative to room coordinates
    x=(x+iw)%iw;//deals with negative x
    y+=dy;//new y position
    y=y%ih;//modulo translates relative to room coordinates
    y=(y+ih)%ih;//deals with negative y
    if(x+cw<iw && y+ch<ih) { //totally inside room
       cx.drawImage(im, x, y, cw, ch, 0, 0, cw, ch); 
    }
    else if(x+cw>=iw && y+ch<ih) { //extends beyond room on right only
        cx.drawImage(im, x, y, iw-x, ch, 0, 0, iw-x, ch);
        cx.drawImage(im, 0, y, x+cw-iw, ch, iw-x, 0, x+cw-iw, ch);
    }
    else if(x+cw<iw && y+ch>=ih) {//extends beyond room at bottom only
        cx.drawImage(im, x, y, cw, ih-y, 0, 0, cw, ih-y);
        cx.drawImage(im, x, 0, cw, y+ch-ih, 0, ih-y, cw, y+ch-ih);
    }
    else {//extends beyond room on right and bottom
        cx.drawImage(im, x, y, iw-x, ih-y, 0, 0, iw-x, ih-y);
        cx.drawImage(im, 0, y, x+cw-iw, ih-y, iw-x, 0, x+cw-iw, ih-y);
        cx.drawImage(im, x, 0, iw-x, y+ch-ih, 0, ih-y, iw-x, y+ch-ih);
        cx.drawImage(im, 0, 0, x+cw-iw, y+ch-ih, iw-x, ih-y, x+cw-iw, y+ch-ih);
    }
}
```